# Is there a way to indent code segment in vim?

Tags: vim

In almost all basic editors in windows I can select few lines of code and indent them back and forth, is there a simple way to do it in vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- in normal/visual mode you can use `>` and `<` to adjust indentation
- in insert mode, you can press `ctrl-t` and `ctrl-d` to adjust indentation
- in command mode, you can still use `:>` and `:<` to adjust indentation

besides, you can try the `=` magic to auto format text.

```
:h =
:h >
:h :>
```

if you want to select lines (visual mode), then indent them back and forth and stay in visual mode, you can have these two lines in your vimrc (I have it in mine):

```
"reselect visual block after indent/outdent 
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```

now you can visual select, then press `>>>> <<<<` to play with the indentations.

P.s

> In almost all **basic** editors in windows I can....

vim is not **basic** editor, so don't bring the old habit to an **advanced** editor. :-)

Comment: You can also forgo the visual mappings and just use `.` to repeat the `>` or `<` command on a selected piece of text. Use `u` if your indention has gone too far